# Creating geohash relationships in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-spatial

I've csv files that contains **latitude/longitude** fields, what i want is to convert this latitude/longitude into a **geohash** and then make a relationship between different location nodes based on their geohash values.
how to do that ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I loaded my csv in neo4j and i just made location nodes with latitude and longitude, i didn't find a way to make a location relationship between them

Comment: i found https://github.com/huashiyiqike/GeoHash_Neo4j but the build dosen't work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neo4j has a [spatial plugin](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial), that creates a R-Tree for your geo-data. So instead of creating a geohash, you can directly use this  plugin.

Moreover, the last version of Neo4j has introduced some new types for properties, and one of them is the `point`. Take a look at the documentation : https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/spatial/

### Update for geohash with spatial plugin

Just create a `geohash layer` :

```
CALL spatial.addPointLayerGeohash('my_geohash_layer_name')
```

And then add your node to the layer :

```
CREATE (n:Node {latitude:60.1,longitude:15.2}) WITH n 
CALL spatial.addNode('my_geohash_layer_name',n) YIELD node 
RETURN node
```

Your nodes must have a `latitude` & `longitude` properties.

Comment: thanks , but i didn't find a clear tutorial on how to do that with R-Tree !?

Comment: did you take a look at this page : http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/spatial/0.24-neo4j-3.1/index.html ? There are some references of tutorials.

Comment: yes i saw them, but since i am new with neo4j i didn't understand a big thing.
is spatial neo4j plugin didn't work in the Basic Neo4j Browser ?
do i need uDig in  order to use it ?

Comment: i found [here](https://neo4j.com/blog/driving-predictive-analytics-neo4j/#comment-138831) that the plugin have a geohash capability.
if you can help me ?

Comment: thanks for your effort,but what that would add ? would it organize the nodes based on their geohash ?

Comment: yes, you will have a geohash tree in your graph, linked to yours nodes. Just install the spatial plugin and try it !

Comment: i try it. actually  after adding the layer, two nodes are connected by a relationship named layer the rest of nodes(added to the layer) aren't connected by any relationship.
if you can add a photo ?

Comment: let me ask you please .did it work with you  or just a try?

Comment: this what your answer do  => [geohash tree question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50913970/how-to-create-geohash-tree-in-neo4j) cordially

Comment: FYI it was a guess, the plugin do a tree when you use an other layer, and my example comes from the unit test of the plugin. I have the same result as you.

Comment: hey @logisima did you know how to fix the length (1-12) for the geohash point layer ?

Comment: Which length are you talking about ?

Comment: it's like a precision just type in google **geohash length** and you will find informations

Answer (score 2):

If you are only working with Point data (latitude and longitude), you do not need to use the spatial plugin at all, and can use the built-in spatial features of Neo4j 3.4. The built-in index is a hilbert space-filling curve, which is a similar concept to a geohash, so I assume it will satisfy your needs. For information on how to use the new features, you can look at either the documentation, or some recent blogs:

- https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/spatial/
- https://medium.com/neo4j/working-with-neo4j-date-and-spatial-types-in-a-react-js-app-5475b5042b50

If you specifically want to use the Neo4j Spatial library and you only want geohash, not the related, and better, hilbert curves, then you can use procedures like `CALL spatial.addPointLayerGeohash('geom')` and then add data with commands like `CREATE (n:Node {latitude:60.1,longitude:15.2}) WITH n CALL spatial.addNode('geom',n) YIELD node RETURN node`.

Comment: actually the geohash layer dosen't work (it creates unrelated nodes unlike in R-tree) you can see the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50913970/how-to-create-geohash-tree-in-neo4j?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: or it is like this ?

Comment: i see you have released a [new version](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial/releases/tag/0.25.5-neo4j-3.4.1) , is the geohash layer is fixed in it ?

Comment: i want to ask how to fix the length of the geohash  in the  layer to 7 for example ??